# how to retrieve azure repo contributors to a web app page

Tags: azure-devops

I'm building a documentation site using `jekyll` in a `azure web app`. It is hosted here right now: [documentation site](https://temphmtest1r6tkzobwhbibw.azurewebsites.net/) I'm using the `azure repo` as a hosting. I would like to know how to retrieve the contributors to each page in the web app from the `azure repo`. It is the same as microsoft docs documentation is, but retrieving the information from azure repo

**An example page**:

[image]

Thank you in advance.